# Malicious ads show on every site

Tags: google-chrome, virus, malware, advertisements

Yesterday my brother's computer was showing ads on almost every site, the same ads in the bottom right corner with a black close button.
Today, my computer started showing them. I use the same network with him but as a public network to minimize the risk of network infection.
The problem is that I NEVER install software from suspicious sources.
Does anyone know something about this virus?
I have some screenshots for some legit sites with those ads. So my computer is infected, no suspisous Chrome extensions or addons. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdwCleaner may help you from this mess please download it and scan your pc from here: https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/

Comment: It gave me 2 Files:
C:\users\ROOT\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\https_static.olark.com_0.localstorage-journal
AND
C:\users\ROOT\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Local Storage\https_static.olark.com_0.localstorage

Comment: It gave me also a Registry Key:
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{90120000-00B2-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}

Comment: What shall I do? delete them or not?

Comment: The article http://www.howtogeek.com/209654/scammers-are-using-a-fake-version-of-adwcleaner-to-trick-people/ provides a different link to download AdwCleaner from, but also recommends MalwareBytes.

Comment: But what about the 2 files and the reg key that it found? Do I have to delete them or is it a false positive

Comment: delete it. those are infected object.